# $http method: "post" not passing data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I use angular's $http like this:

```
$http({
                url: '/api/Movies/UpdateMovie',
                method: "POST",
                data: movie,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

            })
```

inspecting Client side I see movie is correctly filled, but when sending data to server the Movie model does not filled with posted data (or maybe no data is posted to it), I use web api for services. ALSO my movie model at server is:

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Maximum Title length is 256.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256, ErrorMessage = "Maximum Director length is 256.")]
    public string Director { get; set; }

    [Required]        
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

How do I pass movie as data?

Comment: Can we see the data structure of `movie`?

Comment: And can you post the request data sended, using chrome or fiddler for example.

Comment: I tried your code it works very well http://plnkr.co/edit/zQ030iPJ5orYI6tSCQez?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this function:

```
  var param = function (obj) {
        var query = '', name, value, fullSubName, subName, subValue, innerObj, i; for (name in obj) {
            value = obj[name]; if (value instanceof Array) {
                for (i = 0; i < value.length; ++i)
                { subValue = value[i]; fullSubName = name + '[' + i + ']'; innerObj = {}; innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue; query += param(innerObj) + '&'; }
            } else if (value instanceof Object) {
                for (subName in value)
                { subValue = value[subName]; fullSubName = name + '[' + subName + ']'; innerObj = {}; innerObj[fullSubName] = subValue; query += param(innerObj) + '&'; }
            } else if (value !== undefined && value !== null) query += encodeURIComponent(name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value) + '&';
        } return query.length ? query.substr(0, query.length - 1) : query;
    };   // Override $http service's default transformRequest  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = [function(data) {    return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? param(data) : data;  }];});
```

and setting

```
data: param(logOn), headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

Now it works.

Comment: But a better way that in my case worked, was placing: [FromBody] attribute in front of web api's parameter and sending data as Json.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your object to a form data, maybe this gist https://gist.github.com/ghinda/8442a57f22099bdb2e34 be useful to you, anyway you can change the content type to application/json, like this:

headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

Answer (score 0):

In your code try:

```
var movie = {};
movie.Title = "Title";
movie.Director = "Director";
movie.Price = 0.50;
```

and remove: `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }`

```
$http({
   url: '/api/Movies/UpdateMovie',
   method: "POST",
   data: movie
});
```